# LaTeX beamer package and growing figures

Tags: beamer

I'm using `beamer` package in LaTeX to build my slides. I saw in some final examples in LaTeX (I mean, I saw the PDF format and not the tex format), that contains an image that is being build along several slides. For example:

```
On slide1:

>

On slide2:

->

On slide3:

-->

On slide4:

--->
```

Please imagine this picture as an arrow growing.

In this case, I'm building an arrow, but what I really like is having a state diagram appearing along the slides.

Is it possible to build this?

2 - If I have the state diagram as an PDF file, and I import the PDF file to the LaTeX, can I put the feature explained on 1) in the imported file?

Answer (score 5):

In beamer, the `\includegraphics` command understands overlay specifications, so you can do things like

```
\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics<1>[height=2cm]{step1.pdf}%
  \includegraphics<2>[height=2cm]{step2.pdf}%
  \includegraphics<3>[height=2cm]{step3.pdf}%
\end{frame}
```

(taken from the Graphics section in the beamer user manual).

That will include the file `step1.pdf` on the first slide, replace it with `step2.pdf` on the second slide, etc.  You can also have all the `steps` in one pdf file, say `steps.pdf`, as individual pages, and include them as

```
\begin{frame}
  \includegraphics<1>[height=2cm,page=1]{steps.pdf}%
  \includegraphics<2>[height=2cm,page=2]{steps.pdf}%
  \includegraphics<3>[height=2cm,page=3]{steps.pdf}%
\end{frame}
```

I usually use the [Ipe](http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/) graphics editor to create multi-page pdf files that can be used like this, because its concept of layers and views is especially well suited for this.

Another possibility is to create your graphics directly in LaTeX using the `tikz` package.  There are [examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/beamer/) of using tikz to incrementally build pictures for beamer presentations.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I just found this in the Beamer user manual:

> ...some programs, like `xfig`, sometimes also produce series of graphics in which each file just contains the *additional* graphic elements to be shown on the next slide. In this case, the first graphic must be shown not on overlay 1, but from overlay 1 on, and so on. While this is easy to achieve by changing the overlay specification `<1>` to `<1->`, the graphics must also be shown *on top of each other*. An easy way to achieve this is to use TeX’s `\llap` command like this:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The Three Process Stages}

    \includegraphics<1->{first.pdf}%
    \llap{\includegraphics<2->{second.pdf}}%
    \llap{\includegraphics<3->{third.pdf}}
\end{frame}
```

> or like this:

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{The Three Process Stages}

    \includegraphics{first.pdf}%
    \pause%
    \llap{\includegraphics{second.pdf}}%
    \pause%
    \llap{\includegraphics{third.pdf}}
\end{frame}
```

> A more convenient way is to use the `\multiinclude` command, see Section 14.1.3 for details.

Answer (score 2):

I guess not automatic. What I do (and I know others, who handle it same way) is using some overlay environment (like overprint) or multiple frames and simply use different picture files, which show the desired image in its different states.

If you got a .pdf I would recommend inkscape. Use your picture as final picture, then copy the file to file-1.pdf file-2.pdf ... Afterwards open the -X files with inkscape, remove the different contents (Attention: dont change here the cropping!) you dont want on the earlier slides and save them again as pdfs. Aftwerwards include all images in the correct order and voila, you got your growing picture.